# Using NPOI, how do I return a cell value as it has been formatted by Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

Using [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/), is there any buildin possibility to format a cell value (especially numeric and date values) as it has been [formatted by Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)?

If not what would be the best way to implement it? I thought of a formatstring converter from Excel-formatstrings to C#-formatstrings?

The following example assumes the Excel-formatstring and the C#-formatstring are the same. So it works for some basic formatstrings like: "#,##0.00"

```
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;

ICell cell = workbook.GetSheet("table1").GetRow(0).GetCell(0);
string value = null;

if(cell.CellType == CellType.String) {
    value = cell.StringCellValue;
} else if(cell.CellType == CellType.Numeric) {
    string formatString = cell.CellStyle.GetDataFormatString();

    if(DateUtil.IsCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
        value = cell.DateCellValue.ToString(formatString);
    } else {
        value = cell.NumericCellValue.ToString(formatString);
    }
} else [...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the NPOI built in possibility. However some formats like *"Sunday, September 18, 1983"* are evaluated like *"EEEE, September 18, 1983"*.

```
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;

DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
ICell cell = workbook.GetSheet("table1").GetRow(0).GetCell(0);

string value = dataFormatter.FormatCellValue(cell);
```

Comment: [DataFormatter source file](https://npoi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NPOI/SS/UserModel/DataFormatter.cs)

Answer (score -1):

```
private static CellValue EvaluateFormulaCellValue(XSSFWorkbook wb, ICell cell)
        {
             WorkbookEvaluator _bookEvaluator = null;
            _bookEvaluator = new WorkbookEvaluator(XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.Create(wb), null, null);
            // XSSFFormulaEvaluator.EvaluateAllFormulaCells(wb);
            ValueEval eval = _bookEvaluator.Evaluate(new XSSFEvaluationCell((XSSFCell)cell));
            if (eval is NumberEval)
            {
                NumberEval ne = (NumberEval)eval;
                return new NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellValue(ne.NumberValue);
            }
            if (eval is BoolEval)
            {
                BoolEval be = (BoolEval)eval;
                return NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellValue.ValueOf(be.BooleanValue);
            }
            if (eval is StringEval)
            {
                StringEval ne = (StringEval)eval;
                return new NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellValue(ne.StringValue);
            }
            if (eval is ErrorEval)
            {
                return NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellValue.GetError(((ErrorEval)eval).ErrorCode);
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected eval class (" + eval.GetType().Name + ")");
        }
```